# How to append dynamically created div into current mainDiv not all the mainDiv when click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to appendTo a `<div>` into current `<div class='mainDiv'>` when click on a button. Now its appendTo all the `class='mainDiv'` & after the cloning. I need it only to the current clicked `<div>`. Can someone help me to solve it?

```js
(function($) {

  function div2() {
    $('<div/>').addClass('div2').text('This is a Content').appendTo('.mainDiv');
  }

  function cloneIt() {
    $('.mainDiv').clone().detach().appendTo('body');
  }

  $(document).on('click', '.div1', function() {
    div2();
  });

  $(document).on('click', 'span', function() {
    cloneIt();
  });



})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.mainDiv {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

span {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <span>Clone it</span>
  <div class="div1">click to append div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add your code here. because in jsfiddle link you don't added your javascript code

Comment: Thank you for notify me, Please check this one - https://jsfiddle.net/Issact/whtv56wd/

Comment: you have answers below. test them and let them know worked or not for you.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current element bu using `$(this)` and then get the parent using `$(this).parent()` and send it as parameter to the function `div2($(this).parent());` and use it instead of using class selector

```
  function div2(item) {
    $('<div/>').addClass('div2').text('This is a Content').appendTo(item);
  }
```

**See code snippet:**

```js
(function($) {

  function div2(item) {
    if (item.has(".div2").length <= 0) {
      $('<div/>').addClass('div2').text('This is a Content').appendTo(item);
    }
    

  }

  function cloneIt() {
    $('.mainDiv').clone().detach().appendTo('body');
  }

  $(document).on('click', '.div1', function() {
    div2($(this).parent());
  });

  $(document).on('click', 'span', function() {
    cloneIt();
  });



})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.mainDiv {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

span {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDiv">
  <span>Clone it</span>
  <div class="div1">click to append div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Issac do you want the red div (div2) to be just once?

Comment: Yes chiller, I solved it. We can simply use the `length` in condition by checking the `div2` is exist or not. do you have any other solutions?

Comment: That is exactly what i did ... i used the methode .has() :)

Comment: Ohh yes.. `has()` this will also work! by the side which one is more prefered?

Comment: @Issac it depends on the goal, here has() is simple and gets directly the div2 if it exists

Comment: Yes chiller, Your condition code is absolutely working for me now `if (item.has(".div2").length <= 0) {` Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question in the right way, but cloning the current clicked `div` could be solved like this

```js
(function($){

$(document).on('click', '.mainDiv > div', function(){
    $(this).closest('.mainDiv').append($(this).clone(true));
});

})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.mainDiv {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  /* height: 100px; */
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="div1">DIV 1</div>
  <div class="div2">DIV 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the newly created `div` to the correct `.mainDiv` with the following

```js
(function($) {

  function div2(el) {
    $('<div/>').addClass('div2').text('This is a Content').appendTo(el);
  }

  function cloneIt() {
    $('.mainDiv').clone().detach().appendTo('body');
  }

  $(document).on('click', '.div1', function() {
  var el = $(this).parent('.mainDiv');
    div2(el);
  });

  $(document).on('click', 'span', function() {
    cloneIt();
  });



})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.mainDiv {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  cursour: pointer;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

span {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDiv">
  <span>Clone it</span>
  <div class="div1">click to append div</div>
</div>
<div class="mainDiv">
  <span>Clone it</span>
  <div class="div1">click to append div</div>
</div>
<div class="mainDiv">
  <span>Clone it</span>
  <div class="div1">click to append div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Gerard! this will work for me. but is that possible to append it once when we click on button?

Comment: Yes sure. Where should the button be located? Now it works when you click on the blue box.